# How to update prices of products with Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS) API

Tags: amazon-mws

Just tried to find out, how easy (or maybe difficult) it is to update prices of products of a amazon marketplace shop.

After some search I found docs about ["Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS)"](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/docs.html/187-9674165-4743947). I have also checked the API docs and one of the client implementation, but I am not able (or blind, stupid, whatever) to find any docs about setting a price for a specific product.

Or do I need another API?

EDIT: Thanks to @ScottG and @Keyur I found the 'missing link' *Feeds*. http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html# 
For PHP there is a nice example in the [PHP-Client library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/187-9674165-4743947?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=feeds&version=latest) under `src\MarketplaceWebService\Samples\SubmitFeedSample.php`.
See @Keyur's answer for the `_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_` `FeedType` example.

Comment: What platform/language are you using?

Comment: @ScottG nothing yet - just wanted to estimate time it needs for a "simple" price change. I think customer wants me to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to send following Feed to amazon mws feed api, you send price feed of 15 different SKU in one request by looping through  element for each SKU

```
$feed = <<< EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>$merchant_token</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Price</MessageType>
<Message>
  <MessageID>$i</MessageID>
  <Price>
    <SKU>$sku</SKU>
    <StandardPrice currency="$currency">$new_price</StandardPrice>
  </Price>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
EOD;

$feedHandle = @fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
fwrite($feedHandle, $feed);
rewind($feedHandle);

$parameters = array(
    'Merchant' => $MERCHANT_ID,
    'MarketplaceIdList' => $marketplaceIdArray,
    'FeedType' => '_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_',
    'FeedContent' => $feedHandle,
    'PurgeAndReplace' => false, //Leave this PurgeAndReplace to false so that it want replace whole product in amazon inventory
    'ContentMd5' => base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true))
);

$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest($parameters);
$return_feed = invokeSubmitFeed($service, $request);
fclose($feedHandle);
```

Comment: The 15 request quota referenced in Amazon's docs applies to the http requests themselves, not to the number of SKU's in each request.  They recommend, for example, keeping the list to under 30,000 items.

Comment: Is $merchant_token SellerId or MWSAuthToken?

Answer (score 2):

Products are sent to Amazon using Feeds.  We use a third party to handle ours for us, but you can do so yourself using the Feeds API and the [pricing](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html) FeedType.  There are templates you can download to help you out.  You can then use one of the [client libraries](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/187-9674165-4743947?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=feeds&version=latest) to send this feed to Amazon.

Comment: Thanks! Found docs for the submission http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html